# Verifiy if element exists before add to html page

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my current spring project, I have some `<select>` fields where the options inside are added through this jquery code:

```
function load_options(target, lista) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: lista
    }).done(function(data){
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
        $.each(json.item, function(index, item) {
            var option = $('<option class="form-control" value="'+item.id+'">'+item.nome+'</option>');
            if(<<condition>>)
                target.append(option);
        });
    });
}
```

I am looking for a `<<condition>>` where I can verifiy if the option stored in the variable exists before add it to select.

Anyone know how check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery constructor (that's where you pass in your selector) returns an array, so, if an element exists the length property of that array is 1 (or more). You could write you condition based on that.

Comment: you mean something like this: `if (option.length > 0)`?

Comment: No i don't. I mean writing a new jQuery selector that matches the option element and check for it's length

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way, but I'd be interested in other solutions:

```
...
var json = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
var opt = [];
...
if(!opt[item.nome])
  target.append(option);

opt[item.nome]= true;
...
```